# Jspdf wtith Html canvas using addhtml overlapping text in IE issue , image not visible in pdf after extracting

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf, html2canvas

using jspdf with html2canvas plugin. below is my code

```
    createPdf(): void {
    let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4', false);
    let options = {
        pagesplit: true,
        useOverflow: true
    };
    pdf.internal.scaleFactor = 5;
    this.config.showLoading = true;
    pdf.addHTML(this.el.nativeElement, options, () => {
        pdf.save(this.report.code + ".pdf");
        this.config.showLoading = false;
    });

}
```

after extracting the pdf the space between the text is missing in ie but works fine in chrome
tried few css styles of word-wrap, word-spacing . but didnt work.
Also if i have f12 open in IE it works fine